# Google People API - PHP Missing Class

Tags: php, google-api, google-people-api

I am following this quick start tutorial: https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php

In the sample code it references a class like this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);
```

When I install with composer and include the `autoload.php` file, there is a class called:

```
Google_Service_People
```

But not one called:

```
Google_Service_PeopleService
```

When I try called it I get the error:

```
Class 'Google_Service_PeopleService' not found in ...
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? Very frustrating!

Comment: Possibly you have an old version